# JComboBox Selection Change Listener?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I'm trying to get an event to fire whenever a choice is made from a `JComboBox`.

The problem I'm having is that there is no obvious `addSelectionListener()` method.

I've tried to use `actionPerformed()`, but it never fires.

Short of overriding the model for the `JComboBox`, I'm out of ideas.

How do I get notified of a selection change on a `JComboBox`?**

**Edit:** I have to apologize. It turns out I was using a misbehaving subclass of `JComboBox`, but I'll leave the question up since your answer is good.

Comment: Excellent question, since I've noticed that actionPerformed fires on loading a combobox, but NOT on selecting when one would expect it.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

It should respond to [ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), like this:

```
combo.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

[@John Calsbeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965/1429387) rightly points out that `addItemListener()` will work, too.  You may get 2 `ItemEvents`, though, one for the deselection of the previously selected item, and another for the selection of the new item. Just don't use both event types!

Comment: I'd prefer ItemListener (just make sure to check the ItemEvent to see whether it is a selection or deselection even).  The ActionListener can be fired even if the selection hasn't changed (i.e. if the user clicks on the already selected item).  This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: I know this question is old, but in order to complement, ActionListener is also fired if addItem method is called.

Comment: This code is also missing an `@Override`.

Answer (score 185):

Code example of `ItemListener` implementation

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          Object item = event.getItem();
          // do something with object
       }
    }       
}
```

Now we will get only selected item.

Then just add listener to your JComboBox

```
addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
```

Comment: I tried this code, one problem is that when I click the item that is already selected, the listener will not be triggered, because there is no state change.

Comment: @dmark I think this is reasonable, cause nothing was changed. Maybe you should reorganize your actions somehow to not depend on such scenario.

Answer (score 23):

I would try the `itemStateChanged()` method of the [`ItemListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) interface if jodonnell's solution fails.

Answer (score 14):

Here is creating a ComboBox adding a listener for item selection change:

```java
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

comboBox.setBounds(84, 45, 150, 20);
contentPane.add(comboBox);

JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
comboBox_1.setBounds(84, 97, 150, 20);
contentPane.add(comboBox_1);
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

Comment: this answers enhances previous answers in that ... ? Please don't duplicate! Unrelated: never-ever do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: 'Do something' is cryptic, regularly you want to know the source combobox, or selected index

Answer (score 8):

You may try these

```
 int selectedIndex = myComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
```

-or-

```
Object selectedObject = myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

-or-

```
String selectedValue = myComboBox.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

Comment: I know why this was downvoted, but I believe those downvotes should be reconsidered...  If you check the selected index in the actionPerformed method, you'll find that this works.  It does fire, and excluding -1 events will allow you to exclude the false firing on start.  Solved my problem!

Comment: A useful answer, if only as a quick reference to the appropriate methods for JComboBox.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. If there is no event that gets fired you'd have to poll for values. As such this is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I was recently looking for this very same solution and managed to find a simple one without assigning specific variables for the last selected item and the new selected item. And this question, although very helpful, didn't provide the solution I needed. This solved my problem, I hope it solves yours and others. Thanks.

[How do I get the previous or last item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647439/how-to-get-previous-last-item-jcombobox)

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with jdk >= 8

```
getComboBox().addItemListener(this::comboBoxitemStateChanged);
```

so

```
public void comboBoxitemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        YourObject selectedItem = (YourObject) e.getItem();
        //TODO your actitons
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
    cb = new JComboBox<String>();
    cb.setBounds(10, 33, 46, 22);
    panelConfig.add(cb);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cb.addItem(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getID() == temEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED)
            {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox<String>) e.getSource();
                    String newSelection = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
                    System.out.println("newSelection: " + newSelection);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```