# Update JComboBox immediately upon JComboBox selection

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox.  I would like it to work so that if a certain item is selected ("Other"), immediately, several more items are displayed in the same combo box (something like a submenu, but inside the combo box).  I'm having a devil of a time getting this to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what have you tried. in the meantime, take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener

Comment: Why don't you put tree into JCombobox? I think it may satisfy your demand.

Comment: You'd have better luck with a JTree, but basically, you'd have to insert the new items into the DefaultComboBoxModel as a part of the selection listener of the JComboBox.

Comment: @Thinhbk:  please elaborate on your idea of putting tree into JComboBox.

Comment: @SteveCohen: take a look at this implementation: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/tree_inside_jcombobox

Comment: IMO, the idea to put JTree into JCombobox is obvious, but to handle it correctly is actually a tough job.

Comment: I haven't worked with JTrees before and am reluctant to start now.  I am making some progress with using an ItemListener.  The event I want to capture is the Item Selection Event, rather than the action event.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: misunderstood your question!

I assume that you are clicking on an item in the JComboBox? Than simply add this code

```
comboOther.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            comboOther.addItem("new item 1");
            comboOther.addItem("new item 2");
            comboOther.addItem("new item 3");
            // more
        }
});
```

Comment: Please remove your answer before being "bombed" with downvotes.