# Why is setItem on JComboBox is called twice?

Tags: event-handling, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` with a custom Editor.

Why I make a selection from the dropdown list, I find that `setItem()` method of the Editor is called *twice* with the same selected item from the drop list.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353300/jcombobox-only-execute-actionlistener-when-value-changes):

> It fires twice because one item becomes DESELECTED and another becomes SELECTED. Event fires for both. You can check which one occured by calling `e.getStateChange()`.

Comment: Sorry, a little confused: setItem(Object) doesn't take an event. When do I have a hold of of the event?

Comment: If anyone has any thoughts, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure, but an event listener is probably the only way to get the event object.