# Text field not responding to combo box selection

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, string-comparison

Am kind of a beginner. I have an application in which I have  a combo box. The combo box has two strings/items 1 being "Add" and 2nd being "Minus". If I select "Add" from the combo box my jText field should display the word "Addition" and if I select "Minus" from the combo box the jText field should display the word "Subtraction". My issue is it only displays "Addition" if I select add, but if I selects "Minus" it doesn't display "Subtraction".

Is there something wrong with my if statement??

```
    String display ="";

   if (comboBxOperator.getSelectedItem().equals("ADD"))
    {
        display = "Addition";
    }
  else  if (comboBxOperator.getSelectedItem().equals("Minus"))
    {
        display = "Subtraction";
    }
    txtDisplay.setText(display);
```

Update:
After I implemented the acionListener for my combo Box I get"UnsupportedOperationException":

```
comboBxOperator.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: What method contains this code? Also, does your JComboBox contain the Strings "Add" and "Minus" or "ADD" and "MINUS"? These are *very* different.

Comment: How does your code listen to these actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using an [`EventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html), there is no way your program can detect the changes if you don't tell it the selection has changed. Check out this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener) is a simple generic example:

```
combo.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```