# Java JComboBox listen a change selection event

Tags: java, selection, jcombobox

I'm trying to listen to a change of selection in a Java JComboBox. I have tried to use an ActionListener but the problem is this: the action listener does something like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JComboBox<String> source = ((JComboBox<String>)e.getSource());
    String selected = source.getItemAt(source.getSelectedIndex());

    /*now I compare if the selected string is equal to some others 
      and in a couple of cases I have to add elements to the combo*/
}
```

As you can notice, when I need to add elements to the combo another event is fired and the actionPerformed method is called again, even if I don't want that, and the code may loops... :(
Is there any way to listen to the selection change only and not to a generic change event?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener

Answer (score 9):

You can try `itemStateChanged()` method of the [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) interface:

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          Object item = event.getItem();
          // do something with object
       }
    }       
}
```

And add the listener to your JComboBox:

```
source.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
```