# What's the appropriate listener for JComboBox for updating itself?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox which it's items are updating with other parts of program every second. I need a listener when the user tried to type anything there or tried to select an item from JComboBox it updates it's content and show the new items added. I used `actionPerformed` but it is bringing new items but user can not select then I used `itemStateChanged` but the program crashed and I had to close netbeans!

Answer:
My JcomboBox was on the JPanel. The best way I figure out was to add the listener on JPanel so any element on JPanel even JcomboBox get clicked it will update the comboBox.

---

My JcomboBox was on the JPanel. The best way I figure out was to add the listener on JPanel so any element on JPanel even JcomboBox get clicked it will update the comboBox.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener

Comment: It "sounds" like you might have a race condition occurring..Are you using any threads to update the contents?

Comment: @Woody That's for when the user select an item but I want for before that.

Comment: crashed and I had to close netbeans! right I seen that in Netbeans5, time to update

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: My JcomboBox was on the JPanel. The best way I figure out was to add the listener on JPanel so any element on JPanel even JcomboBox get clicked it will update the comboBox.

Comment: sounds weird, most probably you are trying to it the wrong way ..

Answer (score 1):

Events effecting the contents of the combo box are generated by the [model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html).

Try attaching a [`ListDataListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html) to the model itself.

If you are worried about being notified when/if the model changes, you would need to attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JComboBox` and monitor for the `model` property and update your data listeners accordingly...

Comment: I'm trying to initial model with ArrayList but it's giving a syntax error. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think `ComboBoxModel` accepts `ArrayList` as a viable parameter.  Have you tried reading the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html)?

Answer (score 0):

`ItemListener` for when user selects a different item.

`KeyListener` for when the user is typing into the `JComboBox`.

Perhaps your program kept crashing because you weren't using a model for your `JComboBox` (I'm assuming you kept setting all of the items again)

Comment: IMHO - `KeyListener` is a poor choice for monitoring changes to the combo box's editor, as it will not be triggered if the users pastes content into the editor (for example).  A better choice might be a `DocumentListener`, depending on what it is you hope to achieve...

Comment: Yes everytime I remove all item and then I say combo1.addItem()

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah that's what I was thinking but I was under the impression that he wanted to check whether the user is trying to type into the `JComboBox`. Perhaps I misinterpreted. :(

Comment: @JoshM I'd just be careful with `KeyListener`s, they have a number of draw backs, that's alll