# Two data driven JComboBox components

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am using two `JComboBox` components. First combo box gets data from database table.  Second combo box also gets its data from database table and based on data selected in first combo box.  i.e

1. combo box 1 - gets all courses from database.
2. combo box 2 - gets all slots available for selected course from first combo box.

How can I do this?

```
    course = new JComboBox();
    // get all the courses from database
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    ArrayList <String>c =   ConnectDB.getAllCourse();
    for(String co: c)
        {
        model.addElement(co);
        }
    course.setModel(model);
    course.setBounds(135, 136, 86, 20);
    jf.getContentPane().add(course);
```

Then:

```
course.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String course = (String) e.getItem();
            System.out.println(course);
            try {
                ArrayList<String> AvailableSlots = ConnectDB.getAvailableSlots(course);
                System.out.println(ConnectDB.getAvailableSlots(course));
                System.out.println(AvailableSlots);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    slot = new JComboBox();
    slot.setModel(availableSlots);
    slot.setBounds(135, 164, 86, 20);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

You can register a listener to ComboBox1, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener)

Then, based on the selected item you can populate ComboBox2