# Add days to a Java textfield through combobox

Tags: java, combobox, jformattedtextfield

LINK TO GUI IMAGE HERE -------> https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9qyc.jpg

```
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public MainMenu() {
    initComponents();       
    cmbRoomNumber.setEnabled(false);
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);
    btnBook.setEnabled(false);
    //SETTING COMBOBOXES TO NONE
    cmbPhotoId.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    cmbStayDuration.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    //LABELS VALIDATION
    jlblNameVer.setVisible(false);

    //SETTING DATE TODAY
    Date now = new Date();
    //Set date format as you want
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    this.ftxtCheckinDate.setText(sf.format(now));

}
```

As you can see i want to add days to Check-out Date(ftxtCheckOutDate) depending on how many days selected in the combobox(cmbStayDuration)

Im using netbeans JFrame

Thanks :)

```
private void cmbStayDurationActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTime(new Date());

c.add(Calendar.DATE, combobox number);
```

Basically Calendar class has a function to add days.
Get the date now, get the combo box day, then add it.

For example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    c.setTime(d);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));


    c.setTime(d);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

}
```

Output:

```
05/11/2015
15/11/2015
```

As for changing the value of Check-out Date form as the ComboBox changes, you can add either an ActionListener to listen to it change.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener)