# How do I take date as input and add +3 and set label with new date in java swings

Tags: java

How do I take date as input and add 3 in selected date then set label with updated date in java swings? My date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

eg if I enter 2016-04-04 then change date to 2016-04-07 and set a label to it.

i Tried this . .  gives me wring output. 1970-03-01 is ouput
plz  help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537545/add-days-to-a-java-textfield-through-combobox/33537680#33537680 Possibly?

Comment: How many questions do you have?

Comment: just 1 ...how to add +3 from inputed date in specified fomat.. i mean only date should increment

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       Date d = new Date(0);
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
       c.setTime(d);
       c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
    tfDueDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

Comment: gives wrong output

Comment: @muchie see my answer below it's work.

Comment: If you use JAVA 6 or 7, JodaTime Api could help you http://www.joda.org/joda-time/, if use java 8, take a look at this url : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_datetime_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can add 72 hours in date format to create new date with +3 days addition.

```
public String nextDate(String date) { 
  LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date); 
  LocalDate addedDate = parsedDate.plusDays(3); 
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
  return addedDate.format(formatter); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this code:

Declare the following variables:

```
String youdate = "2016-04-04";
    Date mmdate;    
    TextView tv;
```

and use this code:

```
 try {
             mmdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(youdate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(mmdate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        Date newdate = c.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(format.format(newdate));
```

**tv** contains `2016-04-07`