# Why getSelectedItem returns null?

Tags: java

I'm just new learning OOP sorry for this basic post. I don't know why it returns me a null when I'm trying to get the value of the selected item in my `JComboBox`.

```
public class AddEmployee extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame{
   public AddEmployee() 
    {
    initComponents();
    this.setSize(1100,500);
    setMonths();
    setJComboBoxProperties();
    check();
    }

    private void setMonths()
    {
       String[] monthsObj = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

       DefaultComboBoxModel monthsModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(monthsObj);

       cbMonths.setModel((ComboBoxModel)monthsModel);

    }

    private void setJComboBoxProperties()
    {
      cbMonths.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }

    private String check()
    {
       String cb = (String)cbMonths.getSelectedItem();
       System.out.println(cb);
       return cb;
    }

}
```

I cast the `String cb` so it won't give me a null. But I'm trying to check out the selected item but it gives me null.

Comment: where is cbMonth declared? Where is one entry selected?

Comment: @Jens Btw this is drag and drop. That's why I didn't create a instance of `JComboBox` :)

Comment: Drag and drop? You must declare cbMounth.

Comment: Well it wouldn't compile if he hasn't declared `cbMonth`.  I think he means he's using a graphical GUI editor and the cbMonth has been declared in the auto-generated code.

Answer (score 2):

Call `setSelectedItem` after initialize the Combobox. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)).

```
  DefaultComboBoxModel monthsModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(monthsObj);
  monthsModel.setSelectedItem('September');
```

Comment: No. I'm just trying to check which item in drop down is selected by the user.

Comment: @JohnFrancis if you get null, no entry is selected by the user. See the docu i have provided `The combo box value or null for no selection.`

Comment: Check `getSelectedIndex()`. Should return `-1` if not selected.

Comment: @dit OP Calls `getSelectedItem` not `getSelectedIndex`. read the question properbly

Comment: I did not say he should use `getSelectedIndex()`. I mean just to test...

Comment: @dit And what shoulod the test Show? The documentation is very clear

Comment: I don't need to justify myself. By I just wanted to give some other option to debug the issue. But sorry for my suggestion, Your Majesty.

Comment: @Jens I see why it's giving me a `null` value. Because I created a method where I set the `cbMonths` as `selectedIndex(-1)`  How can avoid this null withouth removing `selectedIndex(-1)`? :D

Comment: @JohnFrancis You should Show more all relevant code. You can not. If you use selectedIndex(-1) you unselect all values and then getSelectedItem() Returns null.

Comment: @Jens I updated my post. I tried to remove `selectedIndex(-1)` and check which combobox is selected. But it always print me first the first index of my element. How can I test which element is selected by user?

Comment: @JohnFrancis After a user select a value you have to use getSelectedItem() or getSelectedIndex(). But before a user must select an item

Comment: @JohnFrancis BTW: You should not Change your question because the answers make no scence after you shange your question. Add such Details marked as `UPDATE`

Comment: @Jens Yes I checked that using `String cb = (String)cbMonths.getSelectedItem();` But when the program starts it always gives me the first element. When I select a item from drop down. It doesn't print anything? :D

Comment: @JohnFrancis The method runs only one. If you Need it after a Change, you have to add a listener

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `cbMonths.setSelectedIndex(-1);`.  This sets no item (`null`) as the selected item, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex-int-).

Until the user changes the selection, `getSelectedItem()` will always return `null`.  This is the correct, documented behaviour.

Comment: I tried to removed `setSelectedIndex(-1);` and the first element is January right? It always prints the first element but when I select other element it prints nothing. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to add a listener to react to the ActionEvent triggered when the user changes the selection. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener

Comment: At first I thought I'm not gonna use a Listener. Is this actually the behavior of JComboBox? Just asking :D

Comment: Yes.  In your code, you're printing the selected item _before_ anyone has changed it.  If you want to print the selected item every time it gets changed, then you need to react to the user changing the value.  That's what listeners are for; they allow you to react to Events.  Of course, there could be other triggers for printing the value, like clicking something else, or a periodical timer, or anything you want, really.