# Get Selected Item on JComboBox | JAVA

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I've problem with a JComboBox SelectedItem can someone help me ? 
I've implemented a GUI window where are a various textfield and one JComboBox. When I click button, code must create an Object with the strings of the textfield and string of ComboBox, but I've a `NullPointerException`in `SelectedItem`... The code to get is :

```
(String)combo.getSelectedItem()
```

I tried too:

```
combo.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

but don't work ! 
I don't know if I need a ActionListener but think it's not required.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789141/why-getselecteditem-returns-null

Comment: There isn't way to get an item without modify selection ?

Comment: you can't select *selected* without selecting first

Comment: @user7294900 I tried with try catch , but if I select another item catch again NullPointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

you can get the jcombox selected items like this.

String item = jcombox.getSelectedItem().toString ();

I Placed this code on onclick event of a button and it worked.